# Stopping FOR loop on certain number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uX8ZQ/

Basically I am trying to achieve a continuing `for loop` until a variable gets to a certain number, loading 5 at a time. This is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="go()">Load</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var max=16;
var y=5;

function go(){
    var x="";
    for (var i=1;i<=y;i++){
        if(i>max){
            return;
        }
        x=x + "The count is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
    y=y+5;
}
```

The result I get is the loop stops at `15` and won't load `16`

I am new to JavaScript and trying to learn my way through loops but this one I cannot seem to get.

By the way, in the JSFiddle I have used `window.go = function(){` as JSFiddle will not work by simply defining the function. I am using the above code in my document.

Comment: `return` exits the function. Did you mean `break`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `break` instead of `return` as `return` will exit the function before it gets to update the HTML.

```
function go(){
    var x="";
    for (var i=1;i<=y;i++){
        if(i>max){
            break;
        }
        x=x + "The count is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
    y=y+5;
}
```